# A graph with no even cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the following Theorem:

> Let $G$ be a graph. $G$ has no even cycles if and only if each block of $G$ in its block tree decomposition is either an odd cycle or $K_2$.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction is very straightforward. For the other, suppose that $G$ has a block $B$ that is neither an odd cycle nor $K_2$. $B$ is biconnected (also called $2$-connected), so removing any one vertex from $B$ leaves the graph connected. The only biconnected tree is $K_2$, so $B$ is not a tree and therefore must contain a cycle.

At this point a bit of terminology comes in handy: a *theta graph* is a graph that has two vertices, say $u$ and $v$, that are connected by three simple paths that are disjoint except at the vertices $u$ and $v$. Here’s an example of one:

```
                 x---x---x---x  
                /             \  
             u x-------x---x---x v  
                \             /  
                 x-----------x
```

- Show that if $B$ contains a theta graph, then $B$ must contain an even cycle.
- Show that if $B$ contains more than one cycle, then $B$ must contain a theta graph. HINT: If not, it’s not biconnected.
- Show that if $B$ contains only one cycle, then $B$ is that cycle and is therefore even.